# wordpress widget logic "set_php()... "has been disabled for security reasons

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I saw these solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34082632/warning-ini-set-has-been-disabled-for-security-reasons) however I've implemented (the second suggestion) without resolution. The first suggestion:

> If you have access to your php.ini file look for the
> **disable_functions** item and remove **ini_set** from the list

I have neither in my php.ini. I note these answers are 3 years old...

I have a vps with cpanel access. Disable the Widget Logic plugin and the error goes away. All other plugins, themes and wordpress updated to current versions.

Any other ideas? Advance thanks,

Dave