# Joomla installation error on server

Tags: php, joomla, installation

I am installing Joomla on my live server and it is showing me the following error, help appreciated.

> Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in /root/libraries/joomla/session/handler/joomla.php on line 45
>
> Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in /root/libraries/joomla/session/handler/joomla.php on line 48
>
> Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in /root/libraries/joomla/session/session.php on line 908
> Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "root/libraries/joomla/session/handler/joomla.php" at line 45.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: ini\_set() has been disabled for security reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34082632/warning-ini-set-has-been-disabled-for-security-reasons)

Answer (score 0):

The `ini_set()` function is disabled in your `php.ini` file. If you have access to your php.ini file look for the `disable_functions` item and remove `ini_set()` from the list.

If you do not have access to `php.ini` ask your hosting provider if they can remove it from `disable_functions` item.

Edit:
The best way to find the location of your `php.ini` file it to create a `.php` file with `<?php php_ini_loaded_file(); ?>` in it. Open that file in your browser and there you have the path to your `php.ini` file.

Comment: where can i find php.ini file..?? @tomudding in cpanel

Comment: @raw_hitt check my edit for more information about how you can find your `php.ini` file.